# T-SQL combining XML columns with same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Hey all I have a question about combining like IDs that also have a XML column.

My data I'm trying to combine:

```
_ID    _xml                                                                                              _indivisualCommaList    _eachIndividual
------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ---------------
46589  <Individual><TBS>768-hER-382</TBS><Categories /><TBS2>768-hER-382,908-YTY-354</TBS2></Individual> 768-hER-382,908-YTY-354 768-hER-382
46589  <Individual><TBS>768-hER-382</TBS><Categories /><TBS2>768-hER-382,908-YTY-354</TBS2></Individual> 768-hER-382,908-YTY-354 908-YTY-354
```

Where

> _ID = INT
>
> _xml = XML
>
> _indivisualCommaList = VARCHAR(MAX)
>
> _eachIndividual = VARCHAR(MAX)

Pretty (easier to read) XML from above:

```
<Individual>
  <TBS>768-hER-382</TBS>
  <Categories />
  <TBS2>768-hER-382,908-YTY-354</TBS2>
</Individual>

<Individual>
  <TBS>768-hER-382</TBS>
  <Categories />
  <TBS2>768-hER-382,908-YTY-354</TBS2>
</Individual>
```

The **XML**, **ID** and **_indivisualCommaList** will always be the same no matter how many rows return back. The only unique column would be the **_eachIndividual**.

So I try the following query to group like IDs together

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  @tblData 
WHERE 
  _ID = @AssetID 
GROUP BY 
  _ID
```

Naturally, because of my XML column, I get the error of:

> Column '@tblData._xml' is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

So I'm really not sure what I can do in order to combine these rows?

The end result I am looking to have is:

```
_ID    _xml                                                                                              _indivisualCommaList    _eachIndividual
------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
46589  <Individual><TBS>768-hER-382</TBS><Categories /><TBS2>768-hER-382,908-YTY-354</TBS2></Individual> 768-hER-382,908-YTY-354 768-hER-382,908-YTY-354
```

SO, is this possible to do?

Comment: "The XML, ID and _indivisualCommaList will always be the same" - then aggregate _eachIndividual by ID  only and join it back.

Comment: @Serg Mind showing an example of that?

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: XML needs a root node, what do you want here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution (with horrible performance) without string_agg should be:

```sql
SELECT 
    dataA._id, 
    dataA._xml, 
    dataA._individualCommaList,
    CONCAT(dataA._eachIndividual,',',dataB._eachIndividual) as _eachIndividual
FROM data dataA
JOIN data dataB ON dataA._id = dataB._id AND dataA._eachIndividual != dataB._eachIndividual
WHERE dataA._individualCommaList = CONCAT(dataA._eachIndividual,',',dataB._eachIndividual)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=db63ce44c84a64dde002b5d2f0dcf98b)

JOIN the table onto itself to get the necessary data into one row, but only join different indivduals.
The WHERE Clauses ensures that the record with the correct order is kept.
Alternativley you could use an LIKE to keep the row from the first(?) indivdual in the list.

Comment: That seems to work but seems to have issues if there is a NULL or blank within the **_eachIndividual** column.

Comment: It also seems that if there are more than 2  rows it shows nothing?

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right and for a given `_ID` only `_eachIndividual` is varying

```
select top(1) with ties t._ID, t._xml, t._indivisualCommaList, t2.x as _eachIndividual
from tbl t
join (select _ID, string_agg(_eachIndividual, ',') x
      from tbl
      group by _ID) t2 on t._ID = t2._ID
order by row_number() over(partition by t._ID order by t._ID)
```

Using `for xml path` aggregation in older versions

```
select top(1) with ties t._ID, t._xml, t._indivisualCommaList,
   stuff((select  ',' + t2._eachIndividual 
      from tbl t2
      where t2._ID = t._ID
      for xml path ('')), 
    1,1, '') _eachIndividual 
from tbl t
order by row_number() over(partition by t._ID order by t._ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I am unable to use **string_agg** with my SQL version.

Comment: Do it with  `for xml path`  alternatively. Added this query too.

Comment: Seems to work good. However, I was trying to not do the query using the **TOP 1**.

Comment: What's wrong with `top(1)` , `top(1) with ties` specifically?